# Creating Balance between up- and downvotes is slow and does not work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I have a table with votes for articles.

```
CREATE TABLE `articlevote` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articleid` int NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `vote` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`articleid`,`ipaddress`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUEVOTE` (`articleid`,`ipaddress`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149235 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

For this minimal example, I insert 3 article votes

```
insert into articlevote (id,articleid, ipaddress, vote) values (1,1,"1.2.3.4",1),(2,2,"1.2.3.4",1),(3,1,"1.2.3.5",-1);
```

column vote: 1 = upvote, -1 = downvote
The ipaddress is supposed to prevent double votes.

I have a query to give me the articles with the most upvotes

```
SELECT v.articleid, count(v.vote) as votes FROM articlevote v 
        WHERE v.vote > 0 
        GROUP BY v.articleid 
        ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

But now I need to get a list of the most popular articles considering up- and downvotes.

I tried

```
SELECT v.articleid, sum(v.vote) as votes FROM articlevote v 
        GROUP BY v.articleid 
        ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

I would expect article 2 to be on top with 1 votes and article 1 to be second with 0 votes.
But I get both article 1 and to with 1 votes as total.
On a large dataset the query with the sum aggregate is significantly slower than the one with the count aggregate.

How can I get both the expected result in a performant query?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=35204549009db520a2e5b533d1543d58

Comment: I was using MySQL 8.0.23. I just updated to MySQL 8.0.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the last version of mysql 8 you don't have that problem, maybe a bug, that uis already fixed

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `articlevote` (
>   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `articleid` int NOT NULL,
>   `ipaddress` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
>   `vote` int NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`articleid`,`ipaddress`),
>   UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUEVOTE` (`articleid`,`ipaddress`) USING BTREE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149235 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
> ```

> ```
> insert into articlevote (id,articleid, ipaddress, vote) values (1,1,"1.2.3.4",1)
> ,(2,2,"1.2.3.4",1)
> ,(3,1,"1.2.3.5",-1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT v.articleid, sum(v.vote) as votes FROM articlevote v 
>         GROUP BY v.articleid 
>         ORDER BY votes DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> articleid | votes
> --------: | ----:
>         2 |     1
>         1 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da85472172e146fe82377d53878b8b67)*

Comment: I updated MYSQL on Windows from 8.0.23 to 8.0.26 and I get the correct result now. Thank you. But the performance aspect of the question is not solved.
To give you an idea. The "count-query" has an execution time of 407 milliseconds. The "sum-query" has an execution time of 2.797 seconds. Both were executed on a table with 123'257 rows. That means the "count-query" is almost 7 times faster than the "sum-query".

Comment: make a n index on article_id and votes and if it was helpfil upvote it

Comment: you are the man! It works and is even faster than the "count-query".

Answer (score 0):

- Get rid of `id`; it seems to be totally useless.  Plus it interferes with performance.
- Promote the `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY`
- Don't waste 4 bytes on a value that is either +1 or -1; instead of `INT` use `TINYINT` (1 byte).
- Users in large ISPs share IP addresses -- Two users may have the same IP (at different times) or an infrequent user may get a different IP.
- You are handling IPv4, but not IPv6.
- `COUNT(vote)` checks `vote` for being NOT NULL before including "1" in the total or excluding it.  It does not see the sign of `vote`.

  ```
    CREATE TABLE `articlevote` (
      `articleid` int NOT NULL,
      `ipaddress` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
      `vote` TINYINT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`articleid`,`ipaddress`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
  ```

Comment: Thank you. You make some very good points. I will implement most of it. The IP address check is the closest I could come up with to prevent double votes. It is not perfect and it does not have to be. It mostly prevents users in the same session to up- or downvote multiple times.